# How to show taken picture after taking a picture in android using ImageView and avoid synchronicity problems

Tags: android, image, camera, save, surfaceview

Hello I have an application that is using a SurfaceViews and I would like to show a preview image of the picture taken and a button that let's the user retry taking the picture. The problem I am having is that the Method PictureCallback is an anonymous function that is void so I can't return any file name or id that let's me grab the picture and display it overlaying the SurfaceView along with the retry button. Do you know how I can do this? the PictureCallback() function is here:( I have edited the original, instead of saving to a file I am saving into a global variable so that I can access it later through the my CameraHelper object)

```
// global variable to access the bitmap when the camera callback has finished processing.
private bitmapPicture;
```

Method that takes the picture:

```
  public  void takeThePicture(Camera mCamera)
{
    Log.d("Camera Information","Taking the picture inside takeThePicture() method");

    // picture callback method is required to take a picture
    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // Create a Bitmap picture that we can later access through other way.
            bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }
    };

    mCamera.takePicture(null,null,mPicture);
}
```

This way of accessing the picture has been working the only problem is, it is returning the previous picture that I took, so there is a synchronicity problem with the time of access to the bitmapPicture variable and the time when the data gets saved into it.

Hope you can help me with this :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because PictureCallback is *asynchronous* (and that's why it is **void**). It may take hundreds of milliseconds to capture a picture.

The typical solution is to send a message to the handler of the activity, and let this handler show the image view. This means that your `takePicture(Camera)` method can't be **static**, but have access to parent activity or its handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex, I still don't fully understand how I would be able to communicate my handler and my activity. My activity has 3 fragments inside it, one of them has the ImageView and the camera preview where I take the picture. If I am using a CameraHelper object how would I be able to access from my CameraHelper object my imageView when the picture callback method is called? Or how would I let my Fragment know when the camera has finished taking a photo? Also now instead of creating a file with the image I am sending the data directly into a bitmap to avoid problems with IO delays